# how to draw a line graph from an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, graph

this is my array :

```
<script>
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var i, j, cells;
var distance=[];
var date=[];
var entryid=[];
j=rows.length;
for (i = 1; i < j; i++) {
cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
if (!cells.length) {
continue;
}
distance[i-1] = cells[0].innerHTML;
date[i-1]=cells[1].innerHTML;
entryid[i-1]=cells[2].innerHTML;
}
var c=[];
for (var z=0;z<distance.length;z++){
c.push([distance[z],date[z]]);
}
</script>
```

i want to display the 2D array 'c' in my code as a line graph in a div element of html. using javascript. Thanks in advance :)
EDIT:
using google charts i did this:

```
function drawBackgroundColor() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Distance');
data.addColumn('number', 'Date');

data.addRows(c);

var options = {
hAxis: {
title: 'Time'
},
vAxis: {
title: 'Popularity'
},
backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
};

var chart = new         google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('yo'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

'c' array contains values like this [[3,2016/3/20],[5,2016/3/21],...]
but nothing is getting displayed on the division with id="yo".
Edit *******
i added a domain column ,this is my new code .

```
function drawChart(){
// create DataTable
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Id');
data.addColumn('number', 'distance');
data.addColumn('string', 'date');

// load data
for (var p = 0; p < distance.length; p++) {
var row = [p, distance[p], date[p]];
data.addRow(row);
}

var options = {};

var chart = new    google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('yo'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

but it is not working, not displaying anything. i have written this code in my body element ,and have included the required libraries in the head section . 
distance and date are two 1d arrays , date array contains values in the format 2016/3/19 , should i use a date or a string for its column data type ?

*********************EDIT*******************
this is my code now :

```
<script>
var p=0;
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var i, j, cells;
var distance=[];
var date=[];
var entryid=[];
j=rows.length;
for (i = 1; i < j; i++) {
cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
if (!cells.length) {
    continue;
}
distance[i-1] = cells[0].innerHTML;
date[i-1]=new Date(reverse(cells[1].innerHTML));
entryid[i-1]=cells[2].innerHTML;
}
var c=[];
for (var z=0;z<distance.length;z++){
c.push([date[z],distance[z]]);
}
document.getElementById('cvs').innerHTML=c[0];
function reverse(f){
var g=f.split("/");
var goodstr=g[1]+"/"+g[2]+"/"+g[0];
return goodstr;
}
google.charts.load('44', {
callback: drawBackgroundColor,
packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawBackgroundColor() {
var m = [
[new Date('3/16/2016'), 3],
[new Date('3/17/2016'), 5],
[new Date('3/18/2016'), 7],
[new Date('3/19/2016'), 10],
];

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Distance');

data.addRows(c);

var options = {
hAxis: {
  title: 'Time'
},
vAxis: {
  title: 'Popularity'
},
backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
};

var chart = new    google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('yo'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

this looks so right , but it wont work ...i dont have any idea why ! 
@WhiteHat do thanks a lot man for all your help ,...in the code you gave , if i use the 'm' array that you used in data.addRows() its working ,but when i put my array 'c' its not working :(

Comment: i tried google charts , it didnt work ...i will post what i did .

Comment: looks like you could swap the column order to fix it...

Comment: thanks for all the help WhiteHat ...can you plz look at my latest code and tell why its still not working ?

Comment: after looking more closely, you're first attempt looks close, just make the date the first column, and the value the second -- you can use a string but a date, has to be a date -- `[[new Date('3/20/2016'),3],[new Date('3/21/2016'),5],...]`

Comment: still didnt work , do you know any other way of making a graph?some easy way , a basic line graph will do :)

Comment: did you check the console for any errors? see my answer, just noticed you had the date column set to type `number` -- instead of `date`

Comment: plz see my latest code bro,...is it a scope issue ?

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks a lot man! it worked :) ...my distance array stores numbers but they are actually string , just used parseInt while storing data into distance array !

Comment: cheers! was just looking at the latest, glad you were able to resolve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't *think* you'll find anything *easier*.
Try this, I can add in the HTML table if needed...

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawBackgroundColor,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawBackgroundColor() {
  var c = [
    [new Date('3/16/2016'), 3],
    [new Date('3/17/2016'), 5],
    [new Date('3/18/2016'), 7],
    [new Date('3/19/2016'), 9],
  ];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Distance');

  data.addRows(c);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    },
    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('yo'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="yo"></div>
```